# Iterating over a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Hi I am trying to loop over this list and access a specific value in the nested dictionary

`[{'customer': {'name': 'Karl'}}, {'customer': {'name': 'Smith'}}]`

using this list comprehension

```
[d for d in Account.accountList if d['customer']['name'] == 'smith']
```

but I am getting this `TypeError: string indices must be integers`, I understand this is related to python thinking that my list is a string, but its definetly a list

```
>>> type(Account.accountList)
 <class 'list'>
```

I've tried nested for loops but I keep getting this error, any help would be appreciated..

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__)

class Account:
    accountList = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.customer = Customer(name)
        Account.accountList.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return i
```

Comment: those arent dictionaries ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[d for d in Account.accountList if d.customer.name == 'smith']
```

you were close

the problem is here

```
def __getitem__(self, i):
    return i
```

you can see what happens below

```
MyClass["whatever"] == "whatever" #True
"whatever"["asd"] #error
```

instead I think you could use

```
def __getitem__(self,item):
    return getattr(self,item)
```

Comment: yes there is  ...  d is an instance of `Account` ... not a `dict` ... and `__getitem__` returns a string ...  so yeah that wont work to access his customer attribute ... nor its name attribute ... (since Customer does not implement `__getitem__` at all that I can tell ... at best OP could access it as `d["customer"].name` (if they fix `Account.__getitem__`, if they add a `__getitem__` to customer then they could certainly access it entirely through indicing instead of attribute lookup)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Why is d an instance of `Account`? OP is looping through a list of dictionaries stored  in `Account.accountList`.

Comment: Thanks for that You are right, their was a problem with my  Account.`__getitem__` and it was the thing causing the string error. I've added a `__getitem__` to customer too, and I can access the customer instance using indexing like you said.

Comment: great ... if this answer helped resolve your issue feel free to upvote and accept it ... if you still need help please explain further

Comment: Slightly related question if I wanted to return just the value "smith" could you direct me what to change in the list comprehension roughly?

Comment: could you explain a little more what you mean ... your old code should work if you fixed both `__getitems__` or use the example i listed above ...

Comment: How would I go about outputting just the value of a specific name in this sequence for e.g the output would be `[{'name': 'Foo'}]`

Comment: mmm maybe `print next(d for d in Account.accountList if d['customer']['name'] == 'smith')`  (this assumes you corrected the issues with `__getitem__`

Comment: I think you need to start off by saying "The objects you are accessing are not dictionaries".  As it stands (not your fault), the question title and first line are hugely confusing (they're called dictionaries and their `repr` look like dictionaries but... they're not dictionaries.  Therefore, your answer, although obviously correct (+1), also feels confusing without clarification.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying actually works for me!

Input:

```
details = [{'customer': {'name': 'Karl'}}, {'customer': {'name': 'Smith'}}]

[x for x in details if x['customer']['name'] == 'Smith']
```

Result:
`[{'customer': {'name': 'Smith'}}]`

**EDIT:**
Look closely at this line...
`Account.accountList.append(self)`

It seems you're appending an object to the `AccountList` and not a dictionary as you expect, since `self` is an object. Try:

`Account.accountList.append({'customer': {'name': name}})`

Comment: they arent dictionaries they are(the list you see in the OP)  the repr from his account and customer class ... details is not a list of dicts .... I promise you ... my answer is correct

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes, thanks. I've phrased it a bit differently though.

Comment: in that case have a +1 for providing him a way to make it work :P

Comment: Thanks man, nice solution too, if I wanted to add multiple class instances would I just keep going and add to the append method like `Account.accountList.append({'customer': {'name': name}}, {'cash':{'balance': balance)}`

Comment: @cyclopse87 you could do but it's pretty inefficient. It's better to append the object instance to the list - and work with objects instead of dictionaries. That way you won't forget to update the dictionary if you add a new attribute. My answer was purely to illustrate why your list comprehension wasn't working :)